# What is the most memory efficient way to create a custom Button control?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Okay so I created a custom button control and it has an associated xaml file. My other option is to NOT have an associated xaml file, and just have the button's style defined externally (in Generic.xaml).

When using the former approach, is a new instance of the attached xaml file created for every instance of my button that I create? Or is the system smart enough to just create a single instance of that xaml data and use it for each button?

Comment: The file is probably not held in memory very long. It'll get parsed for whatever information is needed and that will be stored in a memory-efficient structure, one instance per button, either way you do it. I think you should find other things to worry about.

Comment: Do you know that you have a memory problem? Those are rare in a managed run-time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was asking because the plan is to have an instance of the button per ListViewItem that I have in a DataTemplate. The number of elements I have within the DataTemplate is getting pretty high, and so I'm just trying to make the best use I can of memory.

Answer (score 2):

The control's XAML tree is built anew in both cases for each instance of the control you create. You can verify this by putting a custom control that outputs something to the debug console inside its constructor. If you put it in the template or content of a custom control with XAML, in both cases a new instance will get created whenever you create a new one.

However, in `ListView` the situation is a bit different - it features virtualization and reuses its items, so once it loads enough items for display and some buffer for scrolling, it will just keep updating existing instances with data-bound values.

Answer (score 0):

UserControls and TemplatedControls behave differently in these cases. UserControls parse their XAML every single time they are created. TemplatedControls (using genetic.xaml typically) only parse their XAML the first time any instance of the controls is ever created, so should technically be more efficient.